# How to get specific city from detail address in Google Map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

This url has a demo: http://gmaps4rails.heroku.com/locations

When we give a detail address such as "9 Rue du Muret, Marseille", in the Google Map it will show a point.

Now I want to get the specific city "Marseille" through the address. This doesn't contain the street, only the city name.

Is there some way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as doing:

```
  acts_as_gmappable :callback => :save_country 

  def save_country(data)
    #what you need  to do here
  end
```

`data` will contain the full hash from google. in your example it looks like:

> address_components:
>
> - long_name: "9"   types:
>
>   - street_number   short_name: "9"
> - long_name: Rue du Muret   types:
>
>   - route   short_name: Rue du Muret
> - long_name: Les Amavaux   types:
>
>   - neighborhood
>   - political   short_name: Les Amavaux
> - long_name: 14e Arrondissement   types:
>
>   - sublocality
>   - political   short_name: 14e Arrondissement
> - long_name: Marseille   types:
>
>   - locality
>   - political   short_name: Marseille
> - long_name: Bouches-du-Rhone   types:
>
>   - administrative_area_level_2
>   - political   short_name: "13"
> - long_name: "Provence-Alpes-C\xC3\xB4te d'Azur"   types:
>
>   - administrative_area_level_1
>   - political   short_name: PACA
> - long_name: France   types:
>
>   - country
>   - political   short_name: FR
> - long_name: "13014"   types:
>
>   - postal_code   short_name: "13014" types:
> - street_address geometry:    location: 
>     lng: 5.3805084
>     lat: 43.3315919   bounds: 
>     northeast: 
>       lng: 5.3805246
>       lat: 43.3315919
>     southwest: 
>       lng: 5.3805084
>       lat: 43.331585   location_type: RANGE_INTERPOLATED   viewport: 
>     northeast: 
>       lng: 5.3818654802915
>       lat: 43.3329374302915
>     southwest: 
>       lng: 5.3791675197085
>       lat: 43.3302394697085 formatted_address: 9 Rue du Muret, 13014
>     Marseilles, France

Answer (score 2):

Given a model with a known address, automatically fetch address   components and store in separate attributes:

```
geocoded_by :address do |obj,results|
if geo = results.first
  obj.city    = geo.city
  obj.zipcode = geo.postal_code
  obj.country = geo.country_code
end
end
after_validation :geocode
```

Every Geocoder::Result object, result, provides the following data:

```
result.latitude - float
result.longitude - float
result.coordinates - array of the above two
result.address - string
result.city - string
result.state - string
result.state_code - string
result.postal_code - string
result.country - string
result.country_code - string
```

If you’re familiar with the results returned by the geocoding service you’re using, you can access even more data, but you’ll need to be familiar with the particular Geocoder::Result object you’re using and the structure of your geocoding service’s responses.